# Can a system of lenses or compound lens have a higher numerical aperture than a single element in the system?

Tags: optics, visible-light, refraction, lenses, microscopy

I am attempting to create a simple Abbe condenser for a microscope, which typically consists of two converging lenses.

Ideally, I would like to achieve a numerical aperture for the condenser of between 0.75 and 0.8, but all the single element lenses I could use to build the system have much lower NAs. I thought that the NA of a compound lens system (for imaging) would be limited to its’ lowest element’s NA, but this seems incorrect for illumination as Abbe condensers regularly are rated for NAs of >1 in oil.

**In a multi-element lens system, can the NA of the system be greater than the NA of any one element in the system?**

Comment: Yes, but designing one is not as simple as putting two lenses in series. This may be a good starting point for further research. https://www.rp-photonics.com/microscope_objectives.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you go to the wikipedia page about numerical aperture, you will see that the definition has nothing to do with lenses, but with the half-angle of the light cone ($\theta$, assuming everything in air):

$NA=sin(\theta)$

From here it is "easy" to understand that for a single lens one can approximate it as:

$NA\approx\frac{D}{2f}$

With $D$ the diameter of the lens and $f$ its focal length.

However, as soon as you put two lenses in a row, **the definition has to be done for the light cone, rather than for a single element**.

I will however follow up with the simplest case, using approximations, to show that the NA can be much higher. Imagine two lenses with the same diameter ($D_1=D_2=D$), same focal length ($f_1=f_2=f$), separated by 1/4 of their original focal length. We can use the effective focal length formula to find the new $f_n$ effective focal length of such a system:

$\frac{1}{f_n}=\frac{1}{f_1}+\frac{1}{f_2}-\frac{d}{f_1f_2}$

with $d$ as the separation between the two lenses. Then we get:

$f_n=f/1.75$

which in turn, using the approximation $NA\approx\frac{D}{2f}$ means that: $NA_n=1.75*NA_o$, where $NA_n$ is the new effective NA of your system when compared to the original of a single lens $NA_o$. Not only is the new NA much higher, the second lens can also be down to $D_2=\frac{3}{4}D$. As long as $D_2>\frac{3}{4}D$ there is no influence whatsoever on the resulting NA. Being 3/4 smaller means that its NA is also 3/4 of the original.

As an exercise, draw the system I just described and you will see that the half-angle is much steeper for the new system.

So, in conclusion, yes, the NA is defined from the half-angle and it has nothing to do with the single lens NA of a compound system, which can in the end be effectively much higher.